# Execute command from a string

Tags: r, scopus

Using scopus in r to retrieve references

```
library(rscopus)
auth_token_header("please_add")
akey="please_add"
set_api_key(akey)
x = abstract_retrieval("10.1109/TPAMI.2018.2798607", identifier= "doi")
```

Executing this it is possible to take the result

```
x$content$`abstracts-retrieval-response`$`item`$bibrecord$tail$`bibliography`$reference[[1]]$`ref-info`$`ref-title`
```

How is it possible to execute the command and take the result if we have this:

```
a = 1
ref <- paste("x$content$`abstracts-retrieval-response`$`item`$bibrecord$tail$`bibliography`$reference[[",a,"]]$`ref-info`$`ref-title`")
```

Comment: I agree with @DiceboyT, the use of `parse` is often fraught with peril (and often really-difficult-to-troubleshoot bugs). Perhaps you can step back and explain why you want to indirectly reference like this? There might be better ways to accomplish what you *need* vice attacking your problem with this method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `parse` with `eval`:

```
eval(parse(text = "sum(1:10)"))
#[1] 55
```

Although generally you should try to reformulate your problem to avoid having to do this.

```
fortunes::fortune("parse")
#If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
#   -- Thomas Lumley
#      R-help (February 2005)
```