# Run a command from R stored in a R object

Tags: r

I'm developing a Jamovi module for Network Meta-analysis (NMA). I'm using netmeta package to coding some functions for my module.

One of the functions that I will use is *pairwise*. This function converts a database to the proper format in order to perform NMA.

This function get some columns from a database and create a new database with new columns:

```
Test <- paste("Newbase <- pairwise(treat = list(",varsT,"), n=list(",varsN,"), event=list(",varsE,"), data=data, studlab=",varsS,", sm=c('",SM,"'))", sep="")
```

*varsT, varsN, varsE, varsS* are vectors that store the name columns for each information needed to run the command *pairwise*.

How do I run the function stored inside *Test* object?

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Execute command from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427112/execute-command-from-a-string)

Comment: `eval(parse(text = Test))` is what you want. But, usually, you want to avoid doing this.

Comment: I tried to run it but I'm getting the following error message:

Error in eval(mf[[match("treat", names(mf))]], data, enclos = sys.frame(sys.parent())) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'